# How to add CSRF to manually created form in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, csrf

This is my first try to writing custom plugin in WordPress, Certainly there is a way to add CSRF tag to forms in WordPress and check form validity inside server. The question is how can I?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using Wordpress 2.0.4 or above you can use `wp_nonce_field` and `wp_verify_nonce` field to verify. The Wordpress documentation has some [examples](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nonce_field) (which I posted below).

In your form:

```
<form method="post">
   <!-- some inputs here ... -->
   <?php wp_nonce_field('name_of_my_action','name_of_nonce_field'); ?>
</form>
```

In your processing action:

```
<?php
if ( empty($_POST) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['name_of_nonce_field'],'name_of_my_action') )
{
   print 'Sorry, your nonce did not verify.';
   exit;
}
else
{
   // process form data
}
```

**EDIT** Updated [link](https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/security/nonces/) to article on Wordpress site

Comment: WP now has a good article with a more comprehensive guide to using nonces, https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/security/nonces/